# How to use environment variables in batch script conditions?

Tags: batch-file

My batch script is as follows:
VERSION is an environment Variable and %1 is my parameter. How can I use it in condition.

```
if "%1"=="KBA%VERSION%" (

echo %1

) else (

echo %VERSION%

)
```

Comment: Can you explain this a little better? How do you want to use %VERSION%?

Comment: Exactly as you have done - there is nothing wrong with the code you have posted. If it is not giving the result you expect, then you need to post more information about the values of `%1` and `%VERSION%`, the behavior you expect, the behavior you are seeing, and a more specific question.

Comment: %1=KBA14.1 and %VERSION% is 14.1. But this condition does not work in my case. I always get 14.1 as output.

Comment: Hmm.... I figured out the issue. There was a typo error in my code and that was causing me the issue. Sorry guys

Answer (score 0):

you can use it like any other variables...

```
if /I "C:\windows"=="%windir%"  echo "this is the system dir"
```